# Modified cumsum function

Tags: performance, r

Below is a simplified version of a segment of code that I'm working on (a lot of additional calculations are left out to avoid confusion).   It's just a modified form of the `cumsum` function.   I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so does this function already exist?   If not, what scheme would provide the best speed?

```
#Set up the data   
set.seed(1)   
junk <- rnorm(1000000)   
junk1 <- rnorm(1000000)   
cumval <- numeric(1000000)   

#Initialize the accumulator   
cumval[1] <- 1   

#Perform the modified cumsum
system.time({   
for (i in 2:1000000) cumval[i] <- junk[i] + (junk1[i] * cumval[i-1])       
})   

#Plot the result
plot(cumval, type="l")
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more how this is used? Note that `junk[1]` and `junk1[1]` are never used in your algorithm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm is something that fits the `compiler` package perfectly!

```
#Set up the data   
set.seed(1)   
junk <- rnorm(1000000)   
junk1 <- rnorm(1000000)

# The original code
f <- function(junk, junk1) {
  cumval <- numeric(1000000)
  cumval[1] <- 1
  for (i in 2:1000000) cumval[i] <- junk[i] + (junk1[i] * cumval[i-1])
  cumval
}
system.time( f(junk, junk1) ) # 4.11 secs

# Now try compiling it...
library(compiler)
g <- cmpfun(f)
system.time( g(junk, junk1) ) # 0.98 secs
```

...so it would be interesting to know if this algorithm is in any way "typical" - in that case the compiler could perhaps be even more optimized for situations like this...

Answer (score 1):

It is faster but doesn't give correct results.
Run this

```
set.seed(1)

N <- 10

junk  <- rnorm(N)

junk1 <- rnorm(N)

cumval <- numeric(N)
cumval.1 <- numeric(N)
cumval[1] <- 1

for( i in 2:N ) cumval[i] <- junk[i] + junk1[i]*cumval[i-1]
cumval

cumval.1 <- cumsum( junk[-1] + (junk1[-1] * cumval.1[-N]) ) 

cumval.1
```

and you'll see that cumval and cumval.1 are not even the same length.

One needs to rewrite the recurrence relation.
I don't see a way to convert the recurrence to a non recurrence formula.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer, but a comment to the answer by @Seth.  However, your point seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider cumval[5]. Using j[] for junk and jk[] for junk1 and omitting * symbols, its expansion would be:

`j[5] +jk[5]j[4] + jk[5]jk[4]j[3] + jk[5]jk[4]jk[3]j[2] + jk[5]jk[4]jk[3]jk[2]`

The pattern suggests this might be (close to ?) an expression for the 5th term:

```
    sum(  j[1:5] * c(1, Reduce("*" , rev(jk[2:5]), accumulate=TRUE) )
```

Comment: Here's another version of a modified "cumsum" (notice Gabor G's response) that involves "Reduce".  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Cumsum-with-a-max-and-min-value-td3059498.html   I haven't figured why that works yet, but with your solution, something might gel.